# Customize listview item layout

Tags: css, listview, jquery-mobile

What I want is a layout for each list item like:

[image]

But what I'm getting is more like:

[image]

So I want to:

- Put div1 to occupy a specific width, for instance 20px (in percentage would be better...) and is heigth to fill is parent heigth (list item heigth). I already tried put `heigth:100%` but no effect.
- div2 should occupy the rest of the horizontal space with some padding.

How can I manipulate css style to do that?

Below is my code so far:

```
<script id="listItemTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">

    <li class="listItem">
        <div class="div1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="div2">Some content</div>   
    </li>

</script>

<style>
    .ui-li-static.ui-li {
        padding: 0px;
    }

    .listItem div {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .div1{
        width: 20px;
    }

    .div2{
        padding: 15px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I used was:

```
<script id="listItemTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">

    <li class="listItem">
        <div class="div2" style="border-left-color: #{{:CorBack}};">
            Some content
        </div>
    </li>

</script>

<style>

    .ui-li-static.ui-li {
        padding: 0px;
    }

    .div2{
        padding: 15px;
        border-left-width:15px;
        border-left-style:solid;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gZEgU/)

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    display: table-row;
}

.listItem div {
    display: table-cell;
}

.div1 {
    width: 10%;
}

.div2 {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Almost... The only thing that doesn't work is the width of div2. It doesn´t take the rest of the space. It is like before... Could it be something related with jQuery Mobile styles?

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery Mobile 1.3 I used an example using a listview widget from the docs to achieve what I think you are going for.

```
<ul data-role="listview">
    <li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ferrari</a></li>
    <li><div class="div1">test</div><div class="div2wr"><div class="div2">test2</div></div><div class="clr"></div></li>
</ul>

<style type="text/css">
.div1, .div2wr{
    height:30px;    
}
.div1 {
    width: 10%;
    background:black;
    float:left;
}

.div2wr {
    width: 90%;
    float:right;

}
.div2 {
    margin:5px;
    height:20px; /* height must be height of div1/div2wr minus div2 margin X2 */
    background:blue;
}
.clr{
    clear:both;
}
.ui-li-static.ui-li{padding:0px;
}
</style>
```